# Spring Bean Configuration equivalent to <mvc:view-controller path="..." />

Tags: spring-mvc

Trying to figure out what the equivalent `@Bean` configuration would be for the XML element

```
<mvc:view-controller path="..." />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An example of forwarding a request for "/" to a view called "home" in Java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
  }

}
```

And the same in XML use the  element:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home"/>
```

The above example was copied from the [Spring reference docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, knew it was in the documentation somewhere, must have skipped over it!  Thanks a bunch!