# Fastest way to deliver jsp views without xml-conf using spring project stub from start.spring.io

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using spring again after a longer period and happy to see that xml configurations are no longer required in every case.

I want to build a RESTful App, but I still have to deliver the frontend app. I figured the simplest way without using any additional template engines like thymeleaf would be serving a static jsp.

I'm using the project template from start.spring.io with just spring-mvc as dependency, thus i'm using spring boot as well.

I wrote a controller in order to deliver the jsp, but it seems that the mapping for the views has to be configured first.

```
@Controller
public class StaticPagesController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/")
  public String index(){
    return "index";
  }
}
```

So i created a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "de.tuberlin.sense.emp")
public class WebConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");

        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

`index.html` is located in main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/

When i send a request to /, I get a WARN in the logs wich states `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/views/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'`

What am I missing? Can I do this without any xml configuration?

Here is my main application class code:

**UPDATE:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExperimentManagementPlatformApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(ExperimentManagementPlatformApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: `When i send a request to /` vs. `@RequestMapping(value = "/index")`

Comment: @meistermeier you're right. But the typo was just a copy paste error because I was changing the code during editing the question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to serve the static page without needing any controller at all by just adding the html file to the *static* directory. Furthermore i found out that the entire *webapp* directory is not included when the app is deployed as jar which explains why the files in there could not be found.

[The Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a view controller:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049032/spring-bean-configuration-equivalent-to-mvcview-controller-path)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your controller is not being detected, I would suggest to check your file structure, is the StaticPagesController  controller in the de.tuberlin.sense.emp package?  (as stated in:)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "de.tuberlin.sense.emp")
public class WebConfiguration
```

Comment: I think, the StaticPagesController is being detected, because the warning states that `WEB-INF/views/index.html` can't be found, which indicated that at least the index() is called.

Answer (score -1):

Your config class should extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "de.tuberlin.sense.emp")
    public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
        @Bean
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
            viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
            viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");

            return viewResolver;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sry, but this didn't solve the problem. Still can't resolve the view.